# Is there an efficient way to sort an array of objects with parent/child relationships?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, parent-child

I am trying to figure out an efficient way to sort an array where each object can point to the index of a "parent" object in the same array.
Each object can have either no parent(the index is -1) or a single parent, so it's only a many-to-one relationship.
You can chain any number of objects together, creating deep hierarchies.
They are however all in one contiguous array and are added in an arbitrary order.

Here is an example of what an Object looks like:

```
struct Object
{
    void* data;

    int ParentIndex; //Will either be '-1' or will be an index in 'objects' where the parent of this object is.
};

std::vector<Object> objects;
```

It would seem that the only way to do this with a many-to-one relationship is to use deep recursion for each parent.
This however has extremely bad performance.
Does an algorithm exist that could deal with this sort of problem?

Comment: You need Tree array implementation, 4xmpl https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-tree-array-implementation/

Comment: Why does the array need some kind of special sort to let each child point to its parent?  Every parent has a valid index no matter how the array is sorted. Why does it matter that they can be added in arbitrary order?  I think your question is missing important information.

Comment: Are you looking for a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)? If not, what order do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues you must consider:

- theoretically, it may contain a recursive chain. 2 or more objects are each other parent.
- when sort, and you moves a parent object, it must update all of its children.

Therefore, I think the only efficient way is to translate it to a graph (multi children tree) with pointers instead of indexes.

```
struct Object2
{
    void* data;
    Object2* FirstChild; // Will point to first child (if there is), or null.
    Object2* NextSibling;// Will point to next sibling (if there is), or null.
};
```

Actually, you can use any XML library to sort it:

- Any child is just needed to be appended to the parent element.
- When done, you read the elements from the XML and reorder with new indexes.

Comment: I'll be updating the objects in a very tight loop tho, I was hoping I could get away with having them in contiguous memory and just going over the array.  
Unfortunately it really seems like it's impossible to guarantee that parents will be before children.